# effect on jquery created dynamically tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, html

I have a problem with Jquery. I have an xml file that I use to load a list of video information. On each element in the XML I need to see an effect with jquery (fadetoggle etc).

The problem is that it does not work, I show you the code

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({ type:"GET", url:"menu.xml", dataType:"xml",
        success: function(xml){
            $(xml).find("food").each(function(){
                var nome = $(this).find('nome').text();
        var ingredienti = $(this).find('ingredienti').text();

                $("#listapizza").append("<li class=\"list\"><a class=\"acla\" href=\"#\">"+nome+"</a> <div class=\"divHide\" style=\"display:none\">("+ingredienti+")</div></li>");
                });
            },
             error: function(request, error, tipo_errore) { alert(error+': '+ tipo_errore); }
        });

        $(".acla").click(function(){
            $(this).next().fadeToggle(1500);
        });
    });

</script>
```

This is a container of list

```
    <ul id="listapizza">
                    </ul>
```

I can not understand why it does not work

Tnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use event-delegation since it is dynamically appended.

```
$("#listapizza").on("click", ".acla", function(){
    $(this).next().fadeToggle(1500);
});
```